# How to get error code returned by query using MySQL in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, mysql, mysql-connector

I am working with MySQL in my .net web app with the help of MySQL connector 5.0.9.0.
I am getting data from a web service and inserting it in local database. I only want to insert unique rows in my local database. I came to know that when an duplication occurs, MySQL returned an error code: 1062.
All i want to know that how i could i get this code in a variable and check it against my condition like:

```
if(errorCode == "1062")
{
    Response.Write("Record already exists");
}

else
{
    // add the record to database
}
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at MySqlException class members. There is a Number property - *Gets a number that identifies the type of error*.

[MySqlException Class](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlexception).